# twitter-bootstrap modal confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to implement confirm dialog with bootstrap modal, this is my code that doesn't work:

```
<div id="id" class="modal hide">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>confirm message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">No</button>
        <button id="id-confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="a" href="http://example.com">link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var confirmed = false;
    var modal = $('#id');
    var clickee = $('#a');

    clickee.click(function() {
        if (!confirmed) {
            modal.modal('show');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#id-confirm').click(function() {
        confirmed = true;
        clickee.click();
        modal.modal('hide');
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the link `link`, the dialog pops up, but when I confirm it, no redirect happens, when I click on the link `link` again, I get redirected.

I could just redirect to the href of the link, I know that, but I want to make it reusable, instead of link (`a` element) I could also want to use button or define onclick event on the button.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Let me first understand this.

You need to click on a link upon which a bootstrap confirm modal needs to open and then on clicking yes, the user needs to go to a different link?

If that's the case:

```
<a id="a" href="#id" data-toggle="modal">link</a>
```

and then why don't you redirect on button click of id-confirm

You need to remove href="http://example.com" because the bootstrap modal does not know which div should be opened.

Comment: I am opening the div for bootstrap by javascript (and it gets opened, so I don't see a problem here), but when I click on "yes", I want to get the button that triggered the confirm dialog window clicked but this time without prompting for confirmation. Note that it is similar behaviour to this:
    ​<a href="google.com" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?');">link</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: in that case you need to do do a redirect from your javascript after it has been confirmed. I dont understand why you are doing  clickee.click() again. all thats going to do is reopen the modal.

Answer (score 2):

in jQuery, `Click()` does not activate the `<a>`-tag as it was clicked by an user, it will only just call any `onclick=` you have attached.

In fact, `clickee.click();` only calls your anonymous function `clickee.click(function() {`, but nothing happends, because `confirmed` is true (try to insert an alert in `click()` to proof) . When you click again, second time, the click event is not halted (`stopPropagation`) by bootstrap, and now it works like a normal link. Thats what you experience.

I am not completely sure what you want, but if you want to activate the link, after confirm, redirect **is** the easiest way (I know you didnt want that, but you cant do it with `click()` either, *as the code is by now*)

```
$('#id-confirm').click(function() {
     confirmed = true;
     window.location=clickee.attr('href');
     modal.modal('hide');
});
```

would work, and reuseable with other tag types like `<button>`, as long as you have specified a `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library that does a lot of this for you: http://bootboxjs.com. YMMV

Comment: This was perfect! So easy to use.